# I'm having trouble understanding how to work with nodes using python

Tags: python

I think I'm close but there's something I'm missing or not doing right. Im trying to create a new material, and then change the metalic value in the Principled BSDF Node.

```
newmat = bpy.data.materials.new(name)
newmat.use_nodes = True
node_tree = newmat.node_tree
nodes = node_tree.nodes
bsdf = nodes.get("Principled BSDF")
bsdf.inputs[4] = 0.9
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: bpy_prop_collection[key] = value: invalid, expected a StructRNA type or None, not a float
```

Comment: Hi. What happens when you run the script? Please be descriptive of the problem you are having. Questions can be edited by using the [edit] link below it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Set the `default_value` of the input**

*There are many examples of this here, probable duplicate.  Here is an answer in lieu of a long comment*

Set an input node value by altering its `default_value` property

```
import bpy
name = "Foo"
newmat = bpy.data.materials.new(name)
newmat.use_nodes = True
node_tree = newmat.node_tree
nodes = node_tree.nodes
bsdf = nodes.get("Principled BSDF")

bsdf.inputs[4].default_value = 0.9
```

Tip, for new material created as above can

```
>>> bsdf, output = nodes
>>> bsdf
bpy.data.materials['Foo.002'].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"]
```

Testing in python console.

```
>>> import bpy
>>> name = "Foo"
>>> newmat = bpy.data.materials.new(name)
>>> newmat.use_nodes = True
>>> node_tree = newmat.node_tree
>>> nodes = node_tree.nodes
>>> bsdf = nodes.get("Principled BSDF")
>>> bsdf
bpy.data.materials['Foo.002'].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"]

>>> bsdf.inputs[4]
bpy.data.materials['Foo.002'].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[4]
```

Notice the input node is not a float

If we autocomplete the input node, will see its properties and member methods...

```
>>> bsdf.inputs[4].
                   as_pointer(
                   bl_idname
                   bl_rna
                   bl_rna_get_subclass(
                   bl_rna_get_subclass_py(
                   default_value
                   display_shape
                   draw(
                   draw_color(
                   driver_add(
                   driver_remove(
                   ....
```